# SocketIO - Does a browser refresh cause "on disconnect" to fire?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm using SocketIO and I need to disconnect a socket on the server side if the user presses refresh. I've tried implementing this like so:

```
io.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
    socket.close();
})
```

But the `disconnect` event isn't firing. Is this intended behaviour and if so is there any way to disconnect a socket when a page is refreshed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when implemented properly a browser refresh causes a `disconnect` event on the server.  I  just confirmed this with a simple test app.

The `disconnect` event is a `socket` event, not an `io` event.  So, you need to register for it on the socket, not at the `io` level.

This is my event handler that works just fine on my test server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("disconnect: ", socket.id);
    });
});
```

FYI, you do not need to close the socket yourself.  That will happen automatically as all webSocket/socket.io connections are automatically closed whenever a page is refreshed or navigated away from.

Comment: I've read there's an issue with Firefox: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/socket_io/j7mxtHd4n3A ... I know this was 2012 but on their issue tracker others are having similar issues. Could be related, will test on Chrome tonight.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - See what I added to my answer.  Your issue is likely that the `disconnect` event occurs on the `socket` itself, not at the `io` level.  So, you need `socket.on('disconnect', ...)`, not `io.on('disconnect', ...)`.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - My test page and test server has no problem receiving the disconnect event in Firefox on a page refresh when implemented properly.

Comment: Your method does work. The problem is `socket.id` is undefined. Whats even more strange is the follow code removes the `socket.id` from the `clients` array: 
`socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        console.log('Socket disconnected: ' + socket.id);
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
    });`

Comment: @BugHunterUK - `socket` is NOT an argument to the `disconnect` event like you have declared.  You need to inherit that argument from the parent `.on('connection', function(socket) {...})` handler just like in the code I show in my answer.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - Also, there's probably no need for you to maintain your own `clients` array of connected sockets as socket.io already maintains a list of the connected sockets which you can usually just use directly, but I'd have to see must larger context of your code to know what exactly to suggest.

Comment: I was using clients to count the number of users connected.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - An array of connected sockets is in `io.sockets.sockets` so you can use `io.sockets.sockets.length` to see how many currently connected sockets there are.

Comment: That didn't actually work for me, but this did: `io.engine.clientsCount`

Comment: @BugHunterUK - What version of socket.io are you running?  I'm successfully using `io.sockets.sockets.length` in socket.io version 1.3.6.

Comment: @BugHunterUK - OK, I see they've changed it in the latest version v1.4.5.  Man, they muck with the design of socket.io a lot.  It is kind of a moving target.